# angularjs clean input field after submission

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

trying to clear input filed after button is clicked and post saved with angular but it does not work. here is a simple code

```
<!--html-->
<input type="text" ng-model="addField"/>
<button type="button" ng-click="addPost(item)">add</button>

/*script*/
$scope.addField = '';
function addPost(item) {
    /*code for adding*/
    $scope.addField = "";
}
```

Comment: try adding `$scope.nameOfForm.$setPristine();` also.

Comment: I dont have a form, it;s just a single input field

Comment: have you checked if code for adding is working fine or not throwing any error?

Comment: yeah no errors in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `object` instead of `string`, Try this

```
<!--html-->
<input type="text" ng-model="form.addField"/>
<button type="button" ng-click="addPost(item)">add</button>

/*script*/
$scope.form = {};
$scope.addPost = function(item) {
    /*code for adding*/
    $scope.form = {};
}
```

Comment: using $scope.item = {}; does not work, no error but nothing happens